# Handsontable not showing columns with missing data values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable, rhandsontable

According to this example:
https://handsontable.com/docs/binding-to-data/#array-of-objects-with-column-as-a-function

HOT will create missing properties on demand, however I'm not seeing this behavior.

HOT version is 11.1.0

Here's the raw data:

```
let hotData2temp = [
  [40109, "question1", 1, "a1", "a2", "a3"],
  [40110, "question2", 1, "a3", "a4", "a5"],
  [41764, "question3", 2, "jjj", "jjj", "jjj"],
  [41765, "question4", 1, "jj", "jj", "jj", "jj"]
];
```

And here are the column headers:

```
const mcColumnHeaders = ["Card ID","Question","Correct Answer","Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3","Answer 4"];
```

Component settings:

```
const hotSettings2 = {
  data: hotData2temp,
  licenseKey,
  allowInsertRow: true,
  id: 'hot2',
  manualColumnResize: true,
  manualRowResize: true,
  contextMenu: true,
  colHeaders: mcColHeaders,
  rowHeaders: true,
  dropdownMenu: true,
  filters: true,
  width: 1050,
  height: 200
};
```

However when this table gets rendered, the last column (for which the first 3 rows don't have data specified), isn't show initially. If I then manually add a column, the column gets added with the data for row 4 already populated. So the component does have the data, it just isn't showing it upon the initial rendering.

Screencast of the behavior
https://d.pr/i/V34kff

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the possible options for getting all of the data rendered at the beginning.

```
let hotData2temp = [
  [40109, "question1", 1, "a1", "a2", "a3", ''],
  [40110, "question2", 1, "a3", "a4", "a5", ''],
  [41764, "question3", 2, "jjj", "jjj", "jjj", ''],
  [41765, "question4", 1, "jj", "jj", "jj", "jj"]
];
```

You need to create empty, let's say, holders for the rows that don't have any data, and then everything is rendered correctly. That's what adding a column manually does underneath.